# grunt.log.writeln is not displayed in vs code debug console

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, gruntjs

I am trying to debug gruntfile.js in VS Code. My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
   "name: Grunt",
   "type": "node",
   "request": "launch",
   "program": "/usr/local/bin/grunt",
   "args": ["build_script"],
   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
   "stopOnEntry": false,
   "console": "internalConsole"
}
```

It works and I can debug it using breakpoints, etc., but the issue is that all outputs which are done with grunt.log.writeln(..), grunt.fail.warn(..) are not displayed in debug console.

How to make grunt to use the debug console for grunt.log?

Thanks

Comment: I also cannot see `grunt.log.writeln` in vscode debug.

Comment: Finally, I added functions like this `var _writeln = grunt.option('useConsole') ? console.log : grunt.log.writeln;` and use them instead of standard ones.

Comment: Oh interesting thank you!